# Angular 4 - Pipe Orderby Multiple Fields

Tags: angular, angular-pipe

In Angular 4 I have list like below:

```
[{first: 'Peter', last: 'Smith'}
{first: 'John', last: 'Smith'},
{first: 'Tony', last: 'Hornet'},
{first: 'Sarah', last: 'Hornet'}]
```

I need a pipe which will sort the names by last then sort by first. Does anyone know how to best do this?

Comment: You shouldn't use a pipe to sort in the first place, as documented explicitly: https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**: following @JBNizet's comment, created a pipe is actually not the preferred way to go if you have many objects, due to performance reasons.
(https://angular.io/guide/pipes#appendix-no-filterpipe-or-orderbypipe)

So if you've got many objects, you could filter them in your ts code, not in template.

```
array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
  if (!a.last.localeCompare(b.last)) 
  {
    return a.first.localeCompare(b.first);
  }
  return a.last.localeCompare(b.last);
});
```

**Original answer**

Creating a pipe is indeed a good solution

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sortwithName'
})
export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: any[], field: string): any[] {
    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (!a.last.localeCompare(b.last)) 
      {
        return a.first.localeCompare(b.first);
      }
      return a.last.localeCompare(b.last);
    });
    return array;
  }

}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-filter-1svqdn?file=app/sortFilterPipe.ts

Comment: Thanks I used array.sort to follow best practices. It works as expected.

Answer (score 1):

You should create a pipe which takes name as a parameter and call it on the specific order.

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core';

@Pipe({
  name: 'sortwithName'
})
export class SortPipe implements PipeTransform {

  transform(array: any[], field: string): any[] {
    array.sort((a: any, b: any) => {
      if (a[field] < b[field]) {
        return -1;
      } else if (a[field] > b[field]) {
        return 1;
      } else {
        return 0;
      }
    });
    return array;
  }

}
```

and in template,

```
 <li *ngFor="let topic of names  | sortwithName: 'last' | sortwithName: 'first'">
```

**[STACKBLITZ DEMO](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-filter-1cy381?file=app%2Fapp.component.html)**

Comment: This will just ignore the first sort, and only sort on first name. Try adding `{first: 'Vera', last: 'Man'}`, to the list to see what I mean

Comment: Angular's pipe are not meant to be used as orderBy.  https://angular.io/guide/pipes#no-filter-pipe